# Shorten Arrows/Lines/Segments Between Coordinates

Tags: r, plot

I am drawing arrows from one set of points to another with `arrows()`. I'd like to shorten the arrows by a common length so that they don't overlap with the label. However, it's not obvious how one does that, given that `arrows()` takes coordinates as input.

For instance, here's an example.

```
x <- stats::runif(12); y <- stats::rnorm(12)
i <- order(x, y); x <- x[i]; y <- y[i]
plot(x,y, main = "Stack Example", type = 'n')
text(x = x, y = y, LETTERS[1:length(x)], cex = 2, col = sample(colors(), 12))
s <- seq(length(x)-1)  # one shorter than data
arrows(x[s], y[s], x[s+1], y[s+1])
```

How do I shorten the arrows so they don't overlap with the labels?

## UPDATE

These are all great answers. In an attempt to come up with something that doesn't presume that points connect in a chain, I wrote the following function, which moves x0y0 (a dataframe where column 1 is x and column 2 is y) closer to xy (same format as x0y0) by absolute distance d.

```
movePoints <- function(x0y0, xy, d){
  total.dist <- apply(cbind(x0y0, xy), 1,
             function(x) stats::dist(rbind(x[1:2], x[3:4])))
  p <- d / total.dist
  p <- 1 - p
  x0y0[,1] <- xy[,1] + p*(x0y0[,1] - xy[,1])
  x0y0[,2] <- xy[,2] + p*(x0y0[,2] - xy[,2])
  return(x0y0)
}
```

Comment: Excellent question.  One possible workaround (if no answer of found) is to adjust the position of the text.  However, this will never be 100% nice.  I'm looking at `arrow.plot` in the `fields` package now.  It has an adjustment for length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in solution, but if you can guarantee that your points are spaced far enough (otherwise drawing arrows would be difficult anyway!) then you can "shrink" the points the arrows are drawn on by the length of the radius of an imaginary circle circumscribing each letter.

Note that, however, since the scale of the x and y axes are different, we have to be careful to **normalize the x and y values before transformation**. The `reduce_length` parameter below is the estimated `%` of the total viewport that a typical letter occupies. You can tweak with this if you want a little more space around the letters. Also be careful to not pick bad colors that make the letter invisible.

Finally, the imperfections are because of different dimensions for different letters. To really address this, we would need a map of letters to micro `x` and `y` adjustments.

```
x <- stats::runif(12); y <- stats::rnorm(12)
i <- order(x, y); x <- x[i]; y <- y[i]
initx <- x; inity <- y
plot(x,y, main = "Stack Example", type = 'n')
text(x = x, y = y, LETTERS[1:length(x)], cex = 2, col = sample(colors()[13:100], 12))
spaced_arrows <- function(x, y, reduce_length = 0.048) {
  s <- seq(length(x)-1)  # one shorter than data
  xscale <- max(x) - min(x)
  yscale <- max(y) - min(y)
  x <- x / xscale
  y <- y / yscale
  # shrink the line around its midpoint, normalizing for differences
  # in scale of x and y
  lapply(s, function(i) {
    dist <- sqrt((x[i+1] - x[i])^2   + (y[i+1] - y[i])^2)
    # calculate our normalized unit vector, accounting for scale
    # differences in x and y
    tmp <- reduce_length * (x[i+1] - x[i]) / dist
    x[i] <- x[i] + tmp
    x[i+1] <- x[i+1] - tmp

    tmp <- reduce_length * (y[i+1] - y[i]) / dist
    y[i] <- y[i] + tmp
    y[i+1] <- y[i+1] - tmp

    newdist <- sqrt((x[i+1] - x[i])^2 + (y[i+1] - y[i])^2)
    if (newdist > reduce_length * 1.5) # don't show too short arrows
      # we have to rescale back to the original dimensions
      arrows(xscale*x[i], yscale*y[i], xscale*x[i+1], yscale*y[i+1])
  })
  TRUE
}
spaced_arrows(x, y)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing that some of the arrows were reversed in @RobertKrzyzanowski's answer when the letters were close so I reduced the factor. I also vectorized the function using hte diff() function:

```
 plot(x,y, main = "Stack Example", type = 'n')
 text(x = x, y = y, LETTERS[1:length(x)], cex = 2)
 gap_arrows <- function(x, fact = 0.075) {
      dist <- sqrt( diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2)
      x0 <- x[-length(x)] + (tmp <- fact * (diff(x)) / dist)
      x1 <- x[-1] - tmp
      y0 <- y[-length(y)] + (tmp <- fact * diff(y) / dist)
      y1 <- y[-1] - tmp
      arrows(x0,y0,x1,y1)
    }

 gap_arrows2(x)
```

I don't really think this is a finished answer, but perhaps useful? I think using a factor ratehr than an absolute reduction creates some  shortening when the line is near horizontal that I don't understand. The G-G transition seems odd (too short) in this data:

```
> dput(x)
c(0.058478488586843, 0.152887222822756, 0.171698493883014, 0.197744736680761, 
0.260856857057661, 0.397151953307912, 0.54208036721684, 0.546826156554744, 
0.633055359823629, 0.662317642010748, 0.803418542025611, 0.83192756283097
)
> dput(y)
c(-0.256092192198247, -0.961856634130129, 0.0412329219929399, 
0.235386572284857, 1.84386200523221, -0.651949901695459, -0.490557443700668, 
1.44455085842335, -0.422496832339625, 0.451504053079215, -0.0713080861235987, 
0.0779608495637108)
```

Comment: Thanks! When I started thinking about how different letters have different centers of mass, my head started hurting and I didn't want to consider all the special cases. For example, as pointed out by Scriven, you can try shifting around text labels as well to make things fit. A final algorithm would need some sort of knowledge about aesthetic packing. Maybe someone will clean this up and turn it into a micropackage sometime.

Comment: p.s. You wrote `0.0y5` -- Did you mean `0.05`? I get `Error: unexpected symbol in "0.0y5"` Also you call `gap_arrows2` but define `gap_arrows`

Comment: Also, the "factor" is a decoy: it is an absolute reduction since I am normalizing to a unit vector. But you're right that I still see some shifty behavior sometimes...

Comment: Still looks like you are increasing x value by 15% or 5% of length at beginning of segment and reduing it by same fraction at end. Same for y.

Comment: Ah ha! The problem is that the axes are of different scales, and the position is being changed by `x` and `y`. We need to know the size of a typical letter in terms of the `x` and `y` coordinates, which means we need to know the size of the view port.

Comment: This means we don't need to think of the radius of the circumscribing circle -- we need the radius along the radial direction of the line of the circumscribing *ellipse*.

Comment: Fixed! I had to normalize the viewport per the discussion above.

Comment: Good work. I cannot add upvotes for further effort. I wouldn't use the term 'viewport' since that is a specific name of objects in the grid plotting functions which this is not.